# Getting the total of table columns

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am new in Java programming so I need some help... I am doing this accumulating thing...

Just like this..

```
Score             Accumulated
10                10
40                50
60                110
and so on.......
```

I have here my code...

```
public int accumulateScores(){

        db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        String query = "SELECT score, (SELECT sum(score) FROM "
                + TABLE_NAME+ ")" + " AS accumulated" + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            Score score = new Score(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getInt(1));




    }
```

What should I do to return the sum of the column score.. Thanks in advance.. Any help will be deeply appreciated..

Comment: You don't need any particular ordering of the scores you're summing?

Comment: I don't need that actually.. I just need to add the content of the column "score" and display it in a textview..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you need in a fairly simple way, just sum all rows with a rowid less than the current one. If you have an auto incrementing key on the table, you may want to use that one instead to get a more predictable ordering of your scores.

```sql
SELECT Score, 
   (SELECT SUM(Score) 
    FROM table_name a 
    WHERE rowid <= table_name.rowid
   ) Accumulated
FROM table_name
ORDER BY rowid
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/2fcd4/2).

EDIT: based on your error sample;

```
SELECT score, 
   (SELECT SUM(score) 
    FROM score_table a
    WHERE a.id <= score_table.id
   ) Accumulated
FROM score_table
ORDER BY id
```

[Another SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/06455/2).

Comment: @edmund02 Seems you removed the error, but you had an extra comma in your create table after `score integer(5)` before you removed it.

Comment: Thanks @Joachim.. It worked like charm... Last question I have here.. How can I display it in a textview?

Comment: @edmund02 That would depend quite a bit on your code. I suggest you create a new question with details on the GUI part you need help with.

Comment: another question if you don't mind... what would be its return value and its return type ? Can I use the column alias for the cursor?

Answer (score 0):

you should use Google more and type this code

SELECT SCORE,
(SELECT SUM(SCORE)
FROM table_name PATING
WHERE rowid <=table_name.rowid
)Accumulated
FROM table_name
ORDER BY rowid